# Text background color height is inconsistent for non-english characters

Tags: flutter

Text background color height is inconsistent for non-english characters. For selected texts, selectionHeightStyle can be used to fix this, but for other cases, the problem is still there.
For example in SelectableText.rich, if a text of non-english characters is with a background color, the color height is still inconsistent.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Home());

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Demo')),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: Text(
          "曾经的我们",
          style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can Edit your question and copy your code into that.

Comment: ok have done that

Comment: I copied your code with "曾经的我们" and then tried it with english characters like "ABCDEF", but both of them had same UI. I really don't understand your problem.

Comment: non-English characters only

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrapping the `Text` with `SizedBox` with a pre-defined `height` would do the trick.